# CSS not working on Google APP Engine I have try lots of method but still same

Tags: css, google-app-engine

Kindly see this link: http://webdeveloperim.appspot.com/

I have try lots of way to work with css but still not working.
My **app.yaml** code:

```
    application: webdeveloperim
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
  secure: always

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Index.html File code:

```
<!-- ==============================================
    CSS
    =============================================== -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/designr-theme-cyan.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/fix.css">
```

Please give me a right solution. thanks.....

Comment: Remove the css from the static files because it's matching your stylesheet handler. keep it like so (gif|png|jpg|ico|js). This for start

Comment: your stylesheets are loading fine - http://webdeveloperim.appspot.com/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css, so the issue is not with your app.yaml. what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Its not effecting on My site. @GwynHowell

Comment: Still not working @JimmyKane

you can see how look there: [www.webdeveloper.im](http://www.webdeveloper.im/) and how looking google app engine [webdeveloperim.appspot.com](http://webdeveloperim.appspot.com/)@GwynHowell

Answer (score 0):

Cut down the complexity of your handlers, make it a running app that you understand how it works and **later** experiment how your app.yaml can become better, match specific extensions etc.

I don't know how your dir structure looks so I'll prompt you to a simple config with static files that can be js, css, etc. I ll keep it simple.

Sample `app.yaml`

This block will make a single file `robots.txt` under the `/` of your project match any request of `http://myapp.appspot.com/robots.txt`

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt
```

This block will match any filename requested under `/js/` of your project. Example `http://myapp.appspot.com/js/jquery.js`

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

Now  I hope you get the point on how you can configure your app.

This is a complete example with css, js, images, robots.txt. Not the best approach but is fairly simple.

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Now the dir structure for the above would look like:

```
/
|-robots.txt
|-js/
|-css/
|-images/
|-main.py
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Still same @Jimmy I have try in your way.
My CSS, JS in sub folder like css, js.